# Защита от парсинга сайта

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Заметил в логах всякую кривую хрень:

То идет куча запросов на не существующие файлы - типа проверяют что за движок или пытаются ломануть

То еще всякая мутотень, могут программу написать которая сайт будет выкачивать (это как бы в теории)

Как можно на php сделать защиту от парсинга сайта?
типа такую же как на яндекс марките?

В целях экономия трафика и мощности сервера

Ну уж очень дрючат ироды

И еще проблема - это поисковики - они тоже дрючат но в бан их никак нельзя

Answer (score 1):

Для поисковиков можно задать период обновления информации на сайте, может тогда меньше начнут?

Насчёт парсинга - что за сайт, что так боитесь за его содержимое? Или что вы подразумеваете под парсингом? Периодически запускают выкачивание всего сайта с целью парсинга?

Comment: Сайт новостной

Вот думаю что могут появиться те кто тоже захочет создать новостной сайт, а чтобы не писать все вручную, сделают парсер который будет автоматически обновлять их сайт, скачивая html код с моего и потом распарсивая его по запчастям...

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj, ну и будут аккуратненько грузить с вас по пару статей в день. Как отличить от обычного пользователя? Берите качеством.

Comment: Да, оригинальные статьи будут появляться сначала у вас, поисковики это учитывают.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно я придумал крутую защиту от парсинга

При входе на сайт запихиваем сессию с уникальным ключом

Потом генерируем кодированный javascript который отправляет с помощью ajax при загрузке сайта этот самый уникальный ключ и устанавливает новую сессию nobot

Короче говоря потом проверяем если допустим 10 заходов на сайт а сессии nobot нет то нафиг в бан

Походу это крутая защита вот только фиг знает гугл и поисковики тоже попадут в бан

Comment: есть парсеры, которые исполняют и javascript тоже. не только html выкачивают.  
ЗЫ для ботов обычно логика в любом случае другая делается если что.

Comment: По какому параметру бан? Усложняете себе и пользователям жизнь.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если я зайду на ваш сайт с отключенным JS, то меня незаслуженно отправят в бан? Не дело это, совсем не дело.

И да, сдаётся мне, что вы несколько заблуждаетесь касательно ценности вашего контента и, как следствие, необходимости его защиты.

Answer (score 0):

С большой вероятностью это просто "хакеры". Боты, пытающиеся определить движок. Вообще никакая не редкость в наше время.

Защитить содержимое от парзинга и при этом отдавать нормальное содержимое поисковикам невозможно.

Про хитрые схемы с AJAX Вам уже написали - это хороший вариант, если замудрить с динамической подгрузкой содержимого, то парзить будет крайне сложно.

Простой вариант сделать задержку загрузки страниц (настраивается, к примеру, в nginx, если он у Вас есть, несложным образом). Исходим из того, что обычный пользователь не может читать по 100 страниц за минуту. Если такое происходит - то это бот (поисковый, хакерский или парзер конкурентов).

Если же огромное количество запросов на несуществующие URI (которые не являются ссылками на старую версию вашего сайта) идет с одного IP, то это "хакеры", детектирующие широко распространенные движки. Их можно просто банить.

Comment: зачем их банить? им нужно не забанишь всех. А вот пустышек подсунуть - самое оно. И не просто пустышек, а с "правильным" содержимым.

Но не нужно забывать, что часто сканируют с компов обычных пользователей, которым проник троян.

Comment: Ну, если нет проблем с производительностью сайта, то можно и не банить.